# Spring boot 2 rest validator called twice when groups are used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller

When I enable the @Validated spring annotation at class level in a Rest controller, 2 validation contexts are generated (each one with a different prefix). The @Validated annotation is required as I want to use 2 different validation groups but as there are 2 validations context all validations are executed twice. I think all validations should be verified only once so:

- Is there any problem with my configuration?
- Have I missed something?

```java
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping
    @Validated
    public class KidController {
        private final KidService kidService;

        public KidController(KidService kidService) {
            this.kidService = kidService;
        }

        @PostMapping
        @Validated(OnRegistrationRequest.class)
        @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
        public KidDTO createKidRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid KidDTO kid) {
            return kidService.saveKid(kid);
        }
    }

    public interface KidValidatorGroup {
        interface OnRegistrationRequest extends Default {
        }

        interface OnCheckInPersist extends Default {
        }
    }


    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @JsonPropertyOrder({"id"})
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public class KidDTO {
        @NotEmpty
        private String id;
        @NotEmpty
        private String firstName;
        @KidAgeConstraint
        private Integer age;
        @NotEmpty(groups = OnCheckInPersist.class)
        private String roomDocId;
        @Valid
        private Set<AnswerDTO> answers;
        @Valid
        private Set<GuardianDTO> guardians;
    }

    @Data
    @Builder
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @FieldStrictDependentConstraint(principalField = "answer", 
       dependentField = "description")
    @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
    public class AnswerDTO {
        @QuestionIdConstraint(groups = OnRegistrationRequest.class)
        private String questionId;
    }
```

I found the 2 contexts when debugging the application and the second one looks with method name like prefix.

[image: Context Image 1]
[image: Context Image 2]

Comment: **@Validated** annotation should only be at the class level. Why is it placed in the method **createKidRegistration** ?

Comment: @SergZenyuk because I need to specify the group to be used.

Comment: I was following this guide https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you have an annotation that triggers validation both on method parameter and on method return value:

```
    @PostMapping
    @Validated(OnRegistrationRequest.class) // this one is "@Valid" with a specified group and will be used for return value validation
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public KidDTO createKidRegistration(@RequestBody @Valid /* this one is for method parameter */ KidDTO kid) {
        return kidService.saveKid(kid);
    }
```

See the different paths that you have in your screenshots. One is `createKidRegistration.kid.firstName` that's the one for parameter. If you only need to validate the passed parameter with s specific group you should try to replace your `@Valid` with `@Validated(OnRegistrationRequest.class)`, and remove the `@Validated` from the method level completely.